# Submitting result of Get call to react class

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to learn about being a full-stack web developer.  I have decided to use the MERN stack.  I am in the midst of trying to write my first "full-stack" application.  However I can't seem to figure out how to store the data from my get call and submit it to the class as a property.  The get call will reach an end point I have set up in nodejs which will make a call to Mongo and return an array of numbers.  The get call below works as I can console.log the number of elements in that array.  I have tried a number of different ways but I can't seem to figure out how to get the number out of the THEN promise and into my class to display on the screen.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const axios = require('axios');

//call with npm build 




    var num = axios.get('/api').then(result => {
                  console.log(result.data.length)
                  return result.data.length;
              })

//Only show how many unused coupons are left. 

var Message = React.createClass({

  render: function () {

    return <h1>There are {this.props.number} coupons left!</h1>

  }//end of of render outer function
})

ReactDOM.render(<Message number={num} />,document.getElementById('content'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, api call is an asynchronous operation, you can't call in a sync way.

And, instead of returning derived from api value, `axios.get` function returns `Promise`, which resolving this value.

Correct solution would be create `<App />` component and call to api in `componentDidMount` lifecycle callback, set corresponding state variable on success response and render `<Message />` component providing this variable to it.

Look at example:

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      num: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var num = axios.get('/api').then(result => {
      this.setState({ num: result.data.length });
    });
  },

  render() {
    if (this.state.num) {
      return <Message number={this.state.num} />
    }
    return <div />
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('content'))
```

Comment: I got an error saying cannot read property num of null.  Do we need to make an getInitialstate? What does the componentDidMount() do?     Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Peter3, yes, we need `getInitialState` function. I updated the question. `componentDidMount` function is a callback, which will be invoked after component will be mounted to dom.

Comment: is the var num = needed then if we are using this.setState?  Still got the same issue. In the Message class do I need to change from this.props.number to a this.state?

Comment: @Peter3, no, you shouldn't change `Message` class. When you are using `setState` `result.data.length` variable is your derived value from api.

Comment: the browser throws this.  from the bundle.js file--
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'num' of null

Comment: It's working now!  Thanks!  so the issue was I had just copied the code above and it didn't have a comma after the getInitialState function.  Woops! always the little things that get you in code.  could I do this with out the var num = and just call axios.get or do I need to set it to a variable?

Comment: @Peter3, you can't assign to `num` variable result of `axios.get`, because it is an async call. `axios.get` returns `Promise` instead of derived value.